# Magento 2: Disable/Remove "ship" Button from sales->order->view (click) -> Ship

Tags: magento2, invoice, shipment

I tried to disable or remove **Ship**  button option from the admin sales orders. [image] 
commented code **Back, Cancel, Send Email, Hold, Invoice, Ship, Reorder, Edit** from thebelow file path but the trick did not work. a little clue will be appreciate please  help.
1> /opt/lampp/htdocs/Shopcore/vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Braintree/Test/TestCase/CreateVaultOrderBackendTest.xml:
2> /opt/lampp/htdocs/Shopcore/vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Braintree/Test/TestCase/UseVaultOnCheckoutTest.xml:
3>/opt/lampp/htdocs/Shopcore/vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Paypal/Test/TestCase/CreateVaultOrderBackendTest.xml:
4>/opt/lampp/htdocs/Shopcore/vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Paypal/Test/TestCase/UseVaultOnCheckoutTest.xml:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below file, You can remove the ship button from the order view page.

> vendor\magento\module-sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php

Remove the below code.

```
if ($this->_isAllowedAction(
            'Magento_Sales::ship'
        ) && $order->canShip() && !$order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()
        ) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_ship',
                [
                    'label' => __('Ship'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
        }
```

Note: Don't forget to override that file in your module.

Hope above solution will work for you.

Comment: thanks for help .. is there any module to override. please post if you have.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom module for override this feature. Please follow the below steps.

Create module.xml in app/code/Nits/Custommodule/etc and add the following code to it:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Nits_Custommodule" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Create registration.php in app/code/Nits/Custommodule and add this code to it:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Nits_Custommodule',
__DIR__
);
```

Now I will override di.xml file. Create di.xml in app/code/Nits/Custommodule/etc/adminhtml and add this code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" type="Nits\Custommodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" />
</config>
```

It’s time to override view block. Create View.php in app/code/Nits/Custommodule/Block/Adminhtml/Order and add this code in it:

```
<?php
namespace Nits\Custommodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View 
{

/**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'order_id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_order';
        $this->_mode = 'view';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->removeButton('delete');
        $this->removeButton('reset');
        $this->removeButton('save');
        $this->setId('sales_order_view');
        $order = $this->getOrder();

        if (!$order) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::actions_edit') && $order->canEdit()) {
            $onclickJs = 'jQuery(\'#order_edit\').orderEditDialog({message: \''
                . $this->getEditMessage($order) . '\', url: \'' . $this->getEditUrl()
                . '\'}).orderEditDialog(\'showDialog\');';

            $this->addButton(
                'order_edit',
                [
                    'label' => __('Edit'),
                    'class' => 'edit primary',
                    'onclick' => $onclickJs,
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'mage-init' => '{"orderEditDialog":{}}',
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::cancel') && $order->canCancel()) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_cancel',
                [
                    'label' => __('Cancel'),
                    'class' => 'cancel',
                    'id' => 'order-view-cancel-button',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'url' => $this->getCancelUrl()
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::emails') && !$order->isCanceled()) {
            $message = __('Are you sure you want to send an order email to customer?');
            $this->addButton(
                'send_notification',
                [
                    'label' => __('Send Email'),
                    'class' => 'send-email',
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getEmailUrl()}')"
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::creditmemo') && $order->canCreditmemo()) {
            $message = __(
                'This will create an offline refund. ' .
                'To create an online refund, open an invoice and create credit memo for it. Do you want to continue?'
            );
            $onClick = "setLocation('{$this->getCreditmemoUrl()}')";
            if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->isGateway()) {
                $onClick = "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getCreditmemoUrl()}')";
            }
            $this->addButton(
                'order_creditmemo',
                ['label' => __('Credit Memo'), 'onclick' => $onClick, 'class' => 'credit-memo']
            );
        }

        // invoice action intentionally
        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::invoice') && $order->canVoidPayment()) {
            $message = __('Are you sure you want to void the payment?');
            $this->addButton(
                'void_payment',
                [
                    'label' => __('Void'),
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getVoidPaymentUrl()}')"
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::hold') && $order->canHold()) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_hold',
                [
                    'label' => __('Hold'),
                    'class' => __('hold'),
                    'id' => 'order-view-hold-button',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'url' => $this->getHoldUrl()
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::unhold') && $order->canUnhold()) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_unhold',
                [
                    'label' => __('Unhold'),
                    'class' => __('unhold'),
                    'id' => 'order-view-unhold-button',
                    'data_attribute' => [
                        'url' => $this->getUnholdUrl()
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::review_payment')) {
            if ($order->canReviewPayment()) {
                $message = __('Are you sure you want to accept this payment?');
                $this->addButton(
                    'accept_payment',
                    [
                        'label' => __('Accept Payment'),
                        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getReviewPaymentUrl('accept')}')"
                    ]
                );
                $message = __('Are you sure you want to deny this payment?');
                $this->addButton(
                    'deny_payment',
                    [
                        'label' => __('Deny Payment'),
                        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getReviewPaymentUrl('deny')}')"
                    ]
                );
            }
            if ($order->canFetchPaymentReviewUpdate()) {
                $this->addButton(
                    'get_review_payment_update',
                    [
                        'label' => __('Get Payment Update'),
                        'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReviewPaymentUrl('update') . '\')'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Magento_Sales::invoice') && $order->canInvoice()) {
            $_label = $order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice() ? __('Invoice and Ship') : __('Invoice');
            $this->addButton(
                'order_invoice',
                [
                    'label' => $_label,
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getInvoiceUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'invoice'
                ]
            );
        }

        /*if ($this->_isAllowedAction(
            'Magento_Sales::ship'
        ) && $order->canShip() && !$order->getForcedShipmentWithInvoice()
        ) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_ship',
                [
                    'label' => __('Ship'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getShipUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
        }*/

        if ($this->_isAllowedAction(
            'Magento_Sales::reorder'
        ) && $this->_reorderHelper->isAllowed(
            $order->getStore()
        ) && $order->canReorderIgnoreSalable()
        ) {
            $this->addButton(
                'order_reorder',
                [
                    'label' => __('Reorder'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getReorderUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'reorder'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to override Magento 2 layout xml file. So, create sales_order_view.xml in app/code/Nits/Custommodule/view/adminhtml/layout and add this code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
   <body>     
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_edit">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Nits\Custommodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

I hope this will help you.

Please let me know if you find any issue.

Comment: I know that it's a very old comment, but why you have changed class in `sales_order_view.xml` when you have already overridden it in `di.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct but the **sales_order_view.xml** file content is giving error in Magento 2.3.5-px. So here is the update code of this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Nits\Custommodule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" name="customsales_order_edit" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```